# Unable to parse XML file using DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have this code:

```
if (file.exists()) {
  Document doc = builder.parse(file);
  NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("property");
  System.out.println("XML Elements: ");
  for (int ii = 0; ii < list.getLength(); ii++) {
```

line 2 gives following exception

```
E:\workspace\test\testDomain\src\com\test\ins\nxg\maps\Right.hbm.xml
...***java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out: connect:could be due to invalid address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:372)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:233)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
```

Answer (score 9):

Parhaps the DocumentBuilder is unsuccessfully trying to access a DTD via a network socket for your XML document?

If there are DTD references in the XML document, try editing them out to prove the cause.

If that fixes your problem, I think you can use an EntityResolver for a more permanent solution, but I've not done it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Brabster is very helpful to me. In my case I have an XML document starting with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE GBSet PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI GBSeq/EN" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_GBSeq.dtd"> ... more to come
```

This caused a problem for DocumentBuilder. I got a time out problem.  The true evil is in the content of the URL: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_GBSeq.dtd:

```
<!-- ============================================
 ::DATATOOL:: Generated from "gbseq.asn"
 ::DATATOOL:: by application DATATOOL version 1.5.0
 ::DATATOOL:: on 06/06/2006 23:03:48
 ============================================ -->

<!-- NCBI_GBSeq.dtd
This file is built from a series of basic modules.
The actual ELEMENT and ENTITY declarations are in the modules.
This file is used to put them together.
-->

<!ENTITY % NCBI_Entity_module PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI Entity Module//EN"  
"NCBI_Entity.mod.dtd">  %NCBI_Entity_module;

<!ENTITY % NCBI_GBSeq_module PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI GBSeq Module//EN" "NCBI_GBSeq.mod.dtd"> %NCBI_GBSeq_module;
```

After deleting

```
<!DOCTYPE GBSet PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI GBSeq/EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_GBSeq.dtd">
```

My program can at least move forward!

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your problem.

Can you get the code, you have to parse, manually?

If yes, try to parse it. I don't think it's the problem of your DocumentBuilder but your network connection. So you have to ensure, that the DocumentBuilder is able to access *every bit* of the xml document.

If your manually stored document fails when it is validated, there will be a different error message.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory and then create a newDocumentBuilder before you parse the file?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
```

Hope this [link](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html) helps.  It definitely helped me earlier today.